# i create this form for strip <script></script> tags but this form not working

Tags: php, javascript, asp.net, html

i create this form for strip `<script></script>` tags but this form not working please any one modify this form to start working

```
<html>
<head>
<script language='javascript'>
  function alfa(s) {
    return s.replace(/<script>[^<\/script>]*<\/script>/g, "");
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<textarea name="txt" style="width: 300px; height: 150px"></textarea><br />
<input type="button" value="Remove script tags" onClick="txt.value=alfa (txt.value)">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are using a character class (everything between `[` and `]`) as some sort of word class, but that isn't how regex behaves. What your character class does is look for any character that is not one of: `<`, `/`, `s`, `c`, `r`, `i`, `p`, `t` or `>`. It would halt at a greater than, less than, division symbol; or any identifier or string with any of the letters in the word "script", then fail to find `</script>` ahead, and the match will fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one

```
s.replace(/<script[ >][\s\S]*?<\/script>/g, "");
```

Your starting tag is not neccesarily `<script>`. The tag name can befollowed by a space and additional attributes.

Also you use the `[]` character class the wrong way.

Comment: As I have already mentioned, dot character doesn't match the newline character.

Comment: Yes you did, but I cold not have seen it while typing my answer, coud I? :)

Comment: Try the latest vesion, with @duri's `[\s\S]`.

Comment: Many thanks Vbence for spending the time for me jsfiddle.net/kPg3c/2 working

Comment: I guess you're new on SO, so let me remind you that you can vote up the answers which were helpful, or even accept the best one. - And youre welcome :)

Answer (score 5):

```
return s.replace(/<script>[\s\S]*?<\/script>/g, "");
```

`[\s\S]` means "any character" (dot in Javascript doesn't match \n), the question mark makes the * "lazy". Use `[^ ]` only for negation of single character.
`[^<\/script>]` means "any character except <, /, s, c, r, i, p, t or >".

Comment: duri i change return s.replace(/<script>[^<\/script>]*<\/script>/g, "");
 in to return s.replace(/<script>[^<\/script>]*<\/script>/g, ""); but this is not working please check my coding its okey!